# How can i achieve a UI like whatsapp chat ui where dates are showing using React native Flatlist

Tags: react-native, chat, whatsapp, react-native-flatlist

[image: This is i circled here is required]How to achieve chat ui like whatsapp where dates are showing in the middle of messages, i am getting an array of message objects with timestamp , i show the messages but not able to show dates like whatsapp , here i used Flatlist in react native , please help me for achieving this ..

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this functionality you need to use https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.68/sectionlist and in `renderSectionHeader` render your date. Of course, you need to prepare your data for it by grouping it by date.

Comment: i alreday implement it i want the   middle position dates like today, yesterday and and date are showing in the middle of the messages ...

Comment: can you add a screenshot to your question, please?

Comment: i edit the screenshot in the question please help how to achieve it